# Portable regular expression library for Lua?

Tags: regex, lua, portability

For my current project, I'll be building a small, portable program in Lua (LuaJIT interpreter).
One of the requirements is regular expression matching - pretty much any standard-like one (e.g. PCRE/PCRE2, but not Lpeg).

Is there a library I could just bundle with the program (source + interpreter + regex library) so it can be ran out of the box, without installations? Preferably Windows, but that doesn't matter much.

Thanks!

Comment: Better use LPEG than regex.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Lrexlib](http://rrthomas.github.io/lrexlib/), which provides bindings of five regular expression library APIs (POSIX, PCRE, PCRE2, GNU, TRE and Oniguruma) to Lua >= 5.1.